# Connecting MetaWear sensor to MbientLab MetaBase App

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bluetooth, sensors

I installed the MetaBase app by MbientLab, so that I may read sensor data in real-time and establish controls. When I build the app to a tablet, I am having the issue of connecting my sensors via Bluetooth.

When it says "Place your MetaSensor here" on the initial loading screen, nothing shows up when I do so with said sensor.

The github I pulled the app from: https://github.com/mbientlab/MetaWear-Android-MetaBase-App

I have charged all the sensors, and made sure they are paired to the tablet beforehand. I am expecting the connection setup to continue once I bring the sensor into range of the tablet, but this is not happening.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess but if you've already paired the sensors to your tablet then they're connecting direct to the tablet before the Metawear app can connect to them. You shouldn't pair or connect them to the tablet first. The app will scan for them and connect them for you.